# HTTP "Content-Disposition: attachment" and downloading files on iOS web browser

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, http, http-headers

I want my users to be able to download a PDF file and have the browser treat it as a file, not just display it (i.e. it has a filename, user gets option to save, etc.).  The following header seems to work well for this everywhere except for iOS:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.pdf
```

iOS just ignores this and displays the image or document.  No big deal, you might think, except I'm doing this in a hidden IFRAME as part of my download page, so the document is never even seen, and it looks like the download failed.

What's the best way to handle this in a cross-browser compatible manner?  Does iOS just ignore this header?  I can't find any spec or mention of this anywhere.

Do I need to check for iOS in request headers and serve the response differently?  I was hoping to avoid this.  Thanks.

P.S. Any other helpful tips related to downloading files etc. in iOS web browsers are appreciated.

CLARIFICATION:  This regarding a regular web site browsed by the mobile Safari browser.  Not a native app.

Comment: Any luck? Got a similar issue.

Comment: Not yet... You, me, and at least 5 other people are still waiting to figure this out.

Comment: For what its worth, here's the way I'm solving this currently: on desktop I submit forms/anchors to a hidden iframe using the target=iframeId trick, on ipad/ipod (determined via userAgent sniffing) however I set the target to _blank to force it to open in a new tab.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I'd like to have a play with this, but don't have an iPhone or iPad at home and can't really justify doing this stuff at work. Is there any browser you know of that I can use for free on a Windows or Linux PC that exhibits the same behavior as the iOS browsers?

Comment: @MarkAmery browserstack.com? The demo of 30 minutes vm time might be enough for this - they're generally pretty generous with what they count as "usage time".

Comment: Wouldn't just starting a network api HTTP GET request or using sockets do something?

Comment: I have the above issue too, i.e. trying to download a *.csv file but the iPad just displays it.  I was looking up solutions and came across this post.  Is there a solution?  Thanks

Comment: Its 2016, and i haven't found a solution to this yet. Believing that Apple has  security policy which doesn't allow to do so.

Comment: It's 2020, and Chrome on iOS still ignores the Content-Disposition header. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=574033)  Using the file storage system now built into iOS, you can download a PDF file streamed this way, but it's still broken on Chrome (iOS).

Answer (score 22):

The mobile Safari browser doesn't support downloading files.

If Safari can display it, it will display. If you have installed other apps that can open the file, Safari will detect it for you.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25678/downloading-and-uploading-files-through-safari-ios

Comment: Hey I am intercepting the UIwebview request and using NSUrlsessionDownload task to download the file. The file name come under "Conetent-Disposition" Now I am facing some issue earlier it was working but now something has change and stop working can u help me ?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, after adding the following to the header

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.pdf"
```

in order to trigger or force a download prompt on iOS in Safari (thus preventing it from opening the file), only works together with setting the target attribute of the link to a hidden iframe. Like this:

```
<iframe style="display:none;" name="iframe_download"></iframe>
<a href="myfile.pdf" target="iframe_download">Link Text</a>
```