# Feature Detect proper handling of Content-Disposition: attachment?

Tags: html, ios, safari, http-headers, browser-feature-detection

There is a [known issue where ios Safari will ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620039/http-content-disposition-attachment-and-downloading-files-on-ios-web-browser) `Content-Disposition: attachment` headers. This is a fairly big problem when trying to trigger downloads from a single page application (I'm using the [iframe hack](http://www.sigil.org/coding/ios6-forced-me-to-do-it/) but open to suggestions if anyone has any others).

I can always test for ios directly:

```
var iosMobile = (function(userAgent){
                return !!(userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) );
            })(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

But I'd rather not browser-sniff. Does anyone know how I can feature detect whether content-disposition is handled properly??