# Save pdf as not open in browser JavaScript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, pdf

For example I have the button:
`Save As`
And I want to enforce saving as not opening pdf document.
I need solution working in mobile browsers. Do you have idea how to do this?

Comment: Where would you expect it to save *to* on an iPhone? Mobile Safari has nothing resembling a file system.

Comment: This sounds like a massive security issue which you should not be allowed to do. People should be able to see the file and then decide for themselves whether they want to download it or not.

Comment: In my case people should be able to open the file few days later (discount cuppon). Information about content will be placed on the banner, so there is no reason to open the file. By the way thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS ignores the `Content-Disposition` header if it is able to open the file inline: see [HTTP "Content-Disposition: attachment" and downloading files on iOS web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620039/http-content-disposition-attachment-and-downloading-files-on-ios-web-browser).

I'm not sure how other (Android) browsers handle this.