# Trigger download prompt on iOS Safari for PDF File

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, download, safari

I am trying to show the iOS users of my web app a (native) download prompt for a PDF file like this one when they click a button/link:

[image: iOS Download prompt]

Unfortunately all I tried resulted in Safari opening the file in a new or current tab. I tried using [FileSaver.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) like this:

```js
saveAs("https://example.com/pdf", "filename.pdf");
```

I tried an `a` tag: (with and without `target="_blank"`)

```html
<a href="https://example.com/pdf">Download</a>
```

I tried using fetch to get the file and use [FileSaver.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to save the `Blob`:

```js
const res = await fetch("https://example.com/pdf", {
        mode: "cors",
        method: "GET",
        cache: "force-cache",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/pdf",
        },
      });

const blob = await res.blob();

saveAs(blob, "filename.pdf");
```

I can control the server response though. These are the headers I currently set

```
Content-Type:  application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Bauhaus%20-%2001-04-2019%2015-59.pdf"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620039/http-content-disposition-attachment-and-downloading-files-on-ios-web-browser/75502299#75502299

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the `Content-Type` header in the server response to `application/octet-stream`, Safari won't recognize the file as PDF, and therefore won't open it and offer the download prompt.

Comment: It is already done. Still opening pdfs instead of downloading them.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue @Antoniossss - were you able to find a way to have PDF's open the prompt?

Comment: No not yet,even FileSaver didnt get it to work.

Comment: @ShaneLoveland I suspect taht this could worki as a 2 step process. User click link-> download pdf, create blobURL, create download link/button for that blob. Then user has to click that another link/button.

Comment: iPhone 14, iOS 16: Changing content-type in the header made the prompt appear on Safari and the download was successful. No such luck for iOS Chrome though