# How to download a pdf file (blob) on mobile iOS Safari/Chrome in 2024

Tags: ios, pdf, safari, blob, mobile-safari

There are plenty of threads around the Internet on this topic but most of them seem to be 3-5+ years old. Or the answers touch upon MacOS Safari.
I'm explicitly asking for Safari on iPhone.

I have the following piece of code:

```
const downloadPdf = async () => {
  try {
    const pdfBinaryRes = await fetchPdfFile()

    if (!pdfBinaryRes.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${pdfBinaryRes.status}`)
    }

    const filename = pdfBinaryRes.headers... //do magic

    const pdfBlob = await pdfBinaryRes.blob()

    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob)

    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = blobUrl
    link.download = filename
    link.click()

    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl)
    }, 250)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

content-type:           application/pdf;charset=UTF-8

content-disposition:    attachment; filename=my-pdf.pdf

iOS Safari/Chrome (iPhone 14, iOS 16, Browserstack) opens the blob URL in the same tab with URL blob:https://....
The pdf file is previewed but I'd like to be able to save it as .pdf file in the file system. How can I get the download prompt with the Download button?

On the contrary browsers on Android save the file (and then open it, but I guess this is another story on its own)

- a.download attribute was not supported in iOS Safari until v13, but now it should be
- [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167341) seems to have been resolved already

Edit:
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865005/trigger-download-prompt-on-ios-safari-for-pdf-file) suggests changing the repose content-type and I indeed get the download prompt on iOS Safari. But it does not do anything for iOS Chrome